# How to change the first slide in Quarto presentation?

Tags: css, r, presentation, quarto

I need to insert the title of my presentation in the first slide inside a textbox in such a way that the background does not compromise the reading of the text.

Let me share my yml here..

````
---
title: "``Predictive Models``"
subtitle: "``Last update:`` ```r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')```"
title-slide-attributes:
    data-background-image: "https://github.com/rhozon/datasets/raw/master/capa_ppt_Felipe.png"
    data-background-size: contain
    data-background-opacity: "number"
format:
  revealjs:
    slide-number: true
    chalkboard: 
      buttons: true
    preview-links: auto
    css: styles.css
    footer: <https://www.brf-global.com/>
---
````

I don´t know how to make it...

Comment: Can you give an example pic of your desired output?

Comment: Obviously that I cannot @shafee. But I solved using this: ```---
title: "===> Modelos Preditivos"
subtitle: "============>_ Last update: `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
title-slide-attributes:
    data-background-image: "https://github.com/rhozon/datasets/raw/master/capa_ppt_Felipe.png"
    data-background-size: contain
    data-background-opacity: "number"
format:
  revealjs:
    incremental: true   
    slide-number: true
    chalkboard: 
      buttons: true
    preview-links: auto
    css: styles.css
    footer: <https://www.brf-global.com/>
--- ```

Comment: If you solved your problem, it would be better to include the solution as an answer to the question.